# ElementNotVisible Exception Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a public site:
http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/

The logic shown below encounters the ElementNotVisibleException.
However, if you uncomment out the two lines that start with "//", as well as comment out the two lines above that code, the code works fine (however this is for a different dropdown than the one I want).

So I am puzzled.
I am able to select from "Rainfall in the last" dropdown just fine.
But using exactly the same method, I cannot select from the "Gage by Location" dropdown.

How do I select from the Gage by Location dropdown?

```
package sdfwe.sdwd.qsde;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Gfgsdrfffde {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running Tests....");
        // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement we;
        String searchText;
        WebElement dropdown;
        //if you comment out the next two lines after these comments and
        // uncomment out the commented lines below, the code works
        searchText = "110:A100_110 Clear Creek @45";
        dropdown = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.k-widget")).get(3);
    //        searchText = "24 Hours";
    //        dropdown = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.k-widget")).get(1);
        System.out.println("Attempting Dropdown Click....");
        dropdown.click();
        System.out.println("Finished running Dropdown Click....");
        Sleep(4);
        //Select dd2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlTimeSpan")));
        //dd2.selectByVisibleText(searchText);
        we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='" + searchText + "']"));
        if (we != null) {
            we.click();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished Selecting Dropdown....");
        //driver.quit();
    }
    public static void Sleep(int i)
    {
        try { Thread.sleep(i * 300); }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) { System.out.println("Unexpected error in sleep"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Selecting by index is always quite unreliable. Either you need to check what in fact `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.k-widget"))` returned and make sure you select the right element, or why not select a desired element directly, e.g. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='(Select Gage)']"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and you need to make these changes for it to work:

```
    searchText = "110:A100_110 Clear Creek @ I-45";
    dropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[aria-owns='ddlGage_listbox']"));
```

Here's the full working code based from your example above.

```
       public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Running Tests....");
    // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for
    // chromedriver.
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement we;
    String searchText;
    WebElement dropdown;
    // if you comment out the next two lines after these comments and
    // uncomment out the commented lines below, the code works
    searchText = "110:A100_110 Clear Creek @ I-45";
    dropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[aria-owns='ddlGage_listbox']"));
    // searchText = "24 Hours";
    // dropdown =
    // driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.k-widget")).get(1);
    System.out.println("Attempting Dropdown Click....");
    dropdown.click();
    System.out.println("Finished running Dropdown Click....");
    Sleep(4);
    // Select dd2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlTimeSpan")));
    // dd2.selectByVisibleText(searchText);
    we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='" + searchText + "']"));
    if (we != null) {
        we.click();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished Selecting Dropdown....");
    // driver.quit();
}
```

Also, for simple selenium scripts, you might want to check https://github.com/codezombies/easytest.

Here's the same script using easytest framework.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try(EasyTest easy = new EasyTest(DriverType.CHROME)) {


        easy.start("http://preview.harriscountyfws.org/");

        easy.newPage(page -> {
           page.click("span[aria-owns='ddlGage_listbox']");

           final String searchText = "110:A100_110 Clear Creek @ I-45";
           page.executeIn("#ddlGage_listbox", container -> {
               page.click("//li[text()='" + searchText + "']");
           });

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your first code.   I got:      Attempting Dropdown Click....
Finished running Dropdown Click....
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[text()='110:A100_110 Clear Creek @ I-45']"}
  I think it is happening on the   we = driver.findelement line because "Finished Running Dropdown click..." printed, although I did not see the dropdown with all the choices.

Comment: sevenFLip, in order for me to get this thing to work, I had to comment out the code:  "printf(Finished Selecting Dropdown").   I don't know.  this is bizarre.

Comment: @SirFartsalot that can't be it though. :( can you try and put sleep in between the calls. i think what's happening is that some elements are not properly loaded yet before selecting and putting actions to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select#ddlGage")));
    Select gageByLocationSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#ddlGage")));
    gageByLocationSelect.selectByVisibleText("110:A100_110 Clear Creek @ I-45");
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: you had some syntax errors that I fixed, however, it did not work.  same problem.  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: still has syntax errors, but I fixed them.  no, did not work.     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector:

Comment: Sorry for that, I've corrected now..and that means element is not located in page.. try increasing the time out to 20